# Floating Action Button not changing color

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I'm new to android and was trying to change my FAB whenever i press the button from my java Class.
Here's the java code

```
btnPrezzoDecrescente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(btnPrezzoDecrescente.isActivated()) {
                    btnPrezzoDecrescente.setActivated(false);
                    btnPrezzoDecrescente.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("black"));
                   
                }else {
                    btnPrezzoDecrescente.setActivated(true);
                    //do stuff
                    btnPrezzoDecrescente.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("white"));
                }
            }
        });`
```

The button is declaread as a `FloatingActionButton` and this piece of code is inside the `OnCreate` method of my Fragment (in this case).

I tried all the `setColor` and `setTint` methods but nothing worked, although the if statement works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In xml use `android:backgroundTint="@color/black"`.

In Java you can use `floatingActionButton.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(),R.color.black));`.

If you want to change the color of icon inside the floatingActionButton use `android:tint="@color/black"` and in java `floatingActionButton.setImageTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(),R.color.black));`

Comment: it says "FloatingActionButton: Setting a custom background is not supported." (i had tried before). For context, my FAB has an image, i don't know if this does matter